# Class Cast Exception using cropimage library

Tags: android, image, crop, classcastexception

I've downloaded a library from [here](https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage)

When I try to use it, I got an exception

```
09-24 11:24:23.428: E/ActivityThread(31526): Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@41fb9d48 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
09-24 11:24:23.428: E/ActivityThread(31526): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@41fb9d48 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
........
09-24 11:24:25.278: E/AndroidRuntime(31526): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.digitalclick.saler/ru.digitalclick.saler.utils.crop.CropImage}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to ru.digitalclick.saler.utils.crop.CropImageView
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Any help, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to cast `ImageView` in `CropImageView`, so this error occurs.

**Use `CropImageView` instead of `ImageView`.**